# How to find how many windows are opened in GNU screen?

Tags: scripting, gnu-screen, gnu, window

I am trying to automate my work flow. I have a script that opens individual window in screen for each IP in a list. Imagine `setupscreen.sh <IP1> <IP2> ...`. After all windows are open, each `ssh`s to the proper server and sets the title to `hostname` on that particular server. I keep window 0 as my utility window from where I execute other scripts. For example I send commands to all windows, loop over each window with 1 second interval, and so on. This is all good, but the problem is, I get the window count from my script when I create them. If I close a window, this is no longer accurate. 
The question is how can I get (through scripting) my window count and if possible the remaining windows indexes.

p.s. 
All clusters I need to login and perform tasks have `screen` and almost non of them have `tmux` and it's hustle to get it there.

Comment: Screen is no longer being actively developed, tmux offers a better solution and is still receiving updates.

Comment: The closest thing I'm aware of would be the windowlist command (Control-A w)

Comment: @Joe I know this but it's not up to me. This is why I have the note on the bottom.

Comment: @JeffSchaller if I can only catch somehow the output of ctrl-a-w ( or better ctrl-a-") I'll be happy.

Answer (score 4):

`screen -Q windows`

will print out your active screen windows with index & title.

Comment: This is pipe-able but you still would catch a pause in the shell script before it would output. Seems very strange to me.

Comment: On the machines I work with, screen is not compiled with -Q.

Comment: It is useful, but will not work in all cases. From [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Windows) of the "windows" command: "_If this list is too long to fit on the terminal's status line only the portion around the current window is displayed._"  So, you are not guaranteed the full list.

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -X msgwait 0 ; screen -Q windows
```

works for me. You may want to restore msgwait to the 5 seconds default value afterwards.

Thanks @nyr